# How to listen a queue all the time in azure service bus and intercept each message

Tags: java, azure, queue, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a ServiceBus in azure with two queues: The first one is where the client send messages(I need to intercept the messages. `QUEUE_IN`) and the second one is the queue where the client receive the messages I sent when I finish to process the messages in the first one(`QUEUE_OUT`).

I need to listen all the time the `QUEUE_IN` and when they sent a message process it and sent a message to the `QUEUE_OUT` with the result.

The problem I have is that I'm not able to intercept the messages in the `QUEUE_IN`, when I run the program I know there are messages in the queue but the program is not able to see them.

```
private void recibirMensaje() throws Exception {   
        QueueClient queueIn= new QueueClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(stringConection, nameQueue),
                ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        this.interceptMessage(queueIn, executorService);
        recibirMensajeCliente.close();
        executorService.shutdown();

    }

private void interceptMessage(QueueClient queueIn, ExecutorService executorService) throws Exception {
        queueIn.registerMessageHandler(new IMessageHandler() {
            public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessage message) {
                if (message.getLabel() != null && message.getContentType() != null
                        && message.getLabel().contentEquals(etiquetaMensajes)
                        && message.getContentType().contentEquals("application/json")) {

                    byte[] body = message.getBody();
                    logger.info("Printing message{}", body);

                }
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
            }

            public void notifyException(Throwable throwable, ExceptionPhase exceptionPhase) {
            }
        },
                // 1 concurrent call, messages are auto-completed, auto-renew duration
                new MessageHandlerOptions(1, true, Duration.ofMinutes(1)), executorService);


    }
```

I don't post the send method because I have not problema with it. I don't know how to listen all the time the `queue_in` and process the messages or how to know if the queue has messages to be processed and how to intercept it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use Azure Functions which has native support to Service Bus Queues. It will listen to your queue and also will inject the message content for you. After that, you can use output bindings to notify consumers when the job is done.

more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=java

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm sorry but this is the first time I use queues and azure, I have been looking for a example but I haven't found it, Can you have some example please ?

Comment: in the link I've post you'll find Service bus Trigger samples (just use the right menu and click over "input" "output" links

Comment: input @FunctionName("sbprocessor")
 public void serviceBusProcess(
    @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "msg",
                             queueName = "myqueuename",
                             connection = "myconnvarname") String message,
   final ExecutionContext context
 ) {
     context.getLogger().info(message);
 }

Comment: output @FunctionName("httpToServiceBusQueue")
@ServiceBusQueueOutput(name = "message", queueName = "myqueue", connection = "AzureServiceBusConnection")
public String pushToQueue(
  @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
  final String message,
  @HttpOutput(name = "response") final OutputBinding<T> result ) {
      result.setValue(message + " has been sent.");
      return message;
 }

Comment: Thanks Thiago. The problem here is that I have not access to the queue in azure, I just know the stringConnection and the name of the queue, but I can't create a HTTP function trigger in azure. I think I need to do it in the way I'm working until now.